# php date time operator

Tags: php, jgrasp

How would i check in php if the time is lets say 12, and if so , carry out some code.
This is what i have so far.

I want code to be carried out at a specific time and only at that time, everyday.

```
 if (date('H') == 20) 
 {
 //code to be carried out

 CODE
 CODE
 CODE
 echo ("lol");
 }
```

however the cocde just seems to be running regardless of the time!

the program will echo lol everytime even if the time is not 8pm.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: `echo date('H')` and see what hour it gives you.

Comment: @Norse H = 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 00 through 23

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ah, did not know. Edited my response.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a php script at a certain time every day then take a look at [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

There is a tutorial on how to set up cron jobs in cPanel, [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Its not echoing out in my tests:

http://codepad.org/7ZvAKHWh

```
g 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 through 12 
G 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23 
h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 01 through 12 
H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 00 through 23
```

Comment: Well then it should run as 20=true. So its working as expected.lol the value of `date('H')` on codepad is `18` soon tobe `19` http://codepad.org/LbKO4FLo but im `20` uk time, its relative of the server time, not your local time.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work except if this is not it --- try and copy from the original source